# How to retrieve element in dataframe column according to its value in another column ans store it in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have file which I open and transform to a dataframe. I want to retriEve element of the first column into to two variable positive and negative in order to form two list.  I implement this code but it produce an error.

Could you kindly help me  ?

```
lexicon = open(os.path.join(fileDir, 'Ressources/Augustin_pol.txt'), 'r', encoding='utf-8')
data = pd.read_csv(lexicon, sep=";", header=None)
data.columns = ["terme", "pol", "pos", "degre"]
print(data)
pol_august_pos = data['terme'].where(data['pol'] == 'positive')
pol_august_neg = data['terme'].where(data['pol'] == 'negative')

print(pol_august_pos)
```

the dataframe look like this :

```
               terme       pol    pos  degre
0           negative  negative    NOM   haut
1        accablement  negative    NOM   haut
2         affliction  positive    NOM   haut
3     anéantissement  negative    NOM   haut
4      consternation  negative    NOM   haut
...              ...       ...    ...    ...
1343          navrer  positive  VERBE   haut
1344          peiner  negative  VERBE  moyen
1345         pleurer  negative  VERBE   haut
1346       terrasser  positive  VERBE   haut
1347             las  negative    ADJ   haut
```

the result of the code above give this :

```
[1348 rows x 4 columns]
0       NaN
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       NaN
4       NaN
       ...
1343    NaN
1344    NaN
1345    NaN
1346    NaN
1347    NaN
```

I want a list not a dataframe

Comment: if I use `read_clipboard` with the data provided, your methods work for me. can you add the result of `data.head().to_dict()` in your question?

Comment: @Ben.T {'terme': {0: 'negative', 1: 'accablement', 2: 'affliction', 3: 'anéantissement', 4: 'consternation'}, 'pol': {0: 'negative', 1: 'negative', 2: 'negative', 3: 'negative', 4: 'negative'}, 'pos': {0: 'NOM', 1: 'NOM', 2: 'NOM', 3: 'NOM', 4: 'NOM'}, 'degre': {0: 'haut', 1: 'haut', 2: 'haut', 3: 'haut', 4: 'haut'}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the slicing functionalities of pandas dataframe with the .loc

data.loc[data.pol ==‘negative’, ‘terme’]

This is the an example for the negative one

Comment: I want to retrieve it as alist and not dataframe